# Recursive map reference in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create a recursive map in F#.

`type RecMap = Map<string, RecMap>`

will not work, because of the cyclic reference to `RecMap`. But why is it that neither

`type RecMap = Map<string, RecMap ref>`

nor

`type RecMap = (Map<string, RecMap>) ref`

works? I thought that making the value type of the map into a `RecMap ref` should have done the trick.

Circumventing the problem by rewriting `RecMap` into a one member record type works,

`type RecMap = { r : Map<string, RecMap> }`

Records are reference types just like `ref`, but why don't refs work in recursive definitions, when records do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial attempts are [type abbreviations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597537), while your last attempt defines a new type.  During compilation, abbreviations are erased via substitution.  Since you've got a cyclic definition (even if it passes through an additional level with the inclusion of `ref`), substitution would never terminate.

I'd probably do this instead:

```
type RecMap = RecMap of Map<string, RecMap>
```